# Calculate x2 if we know distance, x1, y1, y2

Tags: java, math, distance, points

How can I calculate x1 in Java if I know the distance, x2, y1 and y2 of two points.

I made a picture to be easier to understand:

[image]

If we know the x1, x2, y1, y2 is easy to calculate the distance. But if we know the distance? How can I calculate with delta?

Comment: Please show us what have tried

Comment: Exactly as u calculate it on a paper.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there are usually two solutions to this; corresponding to essentially what is a 'reflected' solution.

if `d` is the distance, then `x2` is at

`x1 +/- sqrt(d * d - (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1));`

Where `+/-` means "plus or minus". That is to repeat, `x1` can be in two different places.

Comment: @duffymo: that's not true given that `x1` is known. Refer to the helpful diagram in the question: you get two points (which, in general can be coincident).

Comment: Missed that detail.  Reading too fast, too early in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

```
d^2 = (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2

(x2-x1)^2 = d^2 - (y2-y1)^2

x2-x1 = +- sqrt(d^2 - (y2-y1)^2)

x2 = x1 +- sqrt(d^2 - (y2-y1)^2)
```

Comment: More precisely, it gives two solutions out of two.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the distance, you can use it's formula:

```
d = sqrt(sqr(x2 - x1) + sqr(y2 - y1))
```

With that, you can re-arrange it to find x1 using simple algebra, but I'll let you figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to solve for x2:

```
d = sqrt((x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2)
d^2 = (x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2
d^2-(y1-y2)^2 = (x1-x2)^2
sqrt(d^2-(y1-y2)^2) = (x1-x2)
x2 = x1-sqrt(d^2-(y1-y2)^2)
```

Now, it's just a matter of expressing this in java:

```
double x2 = x1 - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(d, 2) - Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2));
```

Comment: Using `Math.pow(d, 2)` is a really arbitrary and inefficient way to do it, considering that `d * d` is easier to read anyway.

Comment: @Clashsoft: ostensibly that's correct (and I would advise against using `pow` for such small indices), but these days, compilers etc. optimise out the edge cases. Sadly this solution is only partially correct as the answer has dropped one of the roots. The principle is correct though.

Comment: That's still less readable, and some people might not know what `pow` means in this case. Also, I know javac does Maths optimizations, but certainly not for `Math.pow(x, 2)`

Comment: @Clashsoft for me, readability trumps performance, unless there's a killer reason. `Math.pow` seems clearer to me, but it's all in the eye of the beholder. I'm on the fence wrt `d*d` vs. `Math.pow(d, 2)`, but for more "complex" expression, I'd definitely prefer `Math.pow(y1-y2,2)` over `(y1-y2)*(y1-y2)`.